# Remove duplicates by multiple column criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
     ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     FIRST VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     SECOND VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Table filled with some duplicate data. **TestTarget** table have same structure and it filled using following procedural algorithm:

```
DECLARE @first varchar(10), @second varchar(10)
DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
  FOR
    SELECT first, second FROM Test ORDER BY id

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @first, @second
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TestTarget WHERE first=@first OR second=@second)
      INSERT INTO TestTarget (first, second) VALUES(@first, @second)

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @first, @second
  END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Briefly here we checking target table before insert if it already contains such 'first' **OR** 'second' value.

**Example:**

Source table

```
ID  FIRST SECOND
1   A     2
2   A     1
3   A     3
4   B     2
5   B     1
6   B     3
7   B     2
8   B     4
9   C     2
10  C     3

INSERT INTO Test (first, second)
  VALUES ('A', '2'),
         ('A', '1'),
         ('A', '3'),
         ('B', '2'),
         ('B', '1'),
         ('B', '3'),
         ('B', '2'),
         ('B', '4'),
         ('C', '2'),
         ('C', '3')
```

Target table

```
ID  FIRST SECOND
1   A     2
5   B     1
10  C     3
```

Real source table have x*100k rows and at least 2 rows for same 'first' or 'second' column. 
I'm looking for set based solution if it ever possible or please at least something faster than such loop because it takes hours for my real case.

**NOTE** Classic duplicate removals via partition/join/etc. is not the case here because it will produce different results even with different final number of rows.

Comment: The OR you are using is very strange; it leads to a nondeterministic result. Eg: if there are multiple rows with first=A and second=1,2,3 like your case, then it will only write one row with first=A and second=(single value RANDOMLY chosen between 1,2,3). Are you sure this randomness is OK with you? Shouldn't there be an order-by to help choose which of (1,2,3) you would like to keep?

Comment: It is not random, the order of initial cursor in procedural approach matter. By default it ordered by ID so i need to save same order of processing and final results.

Comment: There is no order on the cursor. While unordered selects will appear to have a consistent order, that is just an artefact of the implementation and even a small change to the query can change the order. If you are relying on order then you need to be explicit.

Comment: `C`/`3` should not be an expected result.

Comment: @Richard Agree. Just added

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TestTarget (first, second)
SELECT first,second
FROM Test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Test t2 
    WHERE t2.id>t.id and (t2.first=t.first or t2.second=t.second)
)
```

Comment: This will produce
    A 2
    B 2
    C 2

Comment: Edited, try again now

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any simple set based solution to your problem, I am afraid, but I would hope that something along the following lines would be much faster than your existing cursor:

```
declare @test table
(id int,
first varchar(1),
second varchar(1))

declare @target table
(id int,
first varchar(1),
second varchar(1))

declare @temp table
(id int,
first varchar(1),
second varchar(1))

INSERT INTO @Test (id, first, second)
  VALUES (1, 'A', '2'),
         (2, 'A', '1'),
         (3, 'A', '3'),
         (4, 'B', '2'),
         (5, 'B', '1'),
         (6, 'B', '3'),
         (7, 'B', '2'),
         (8, 'B', '4'),
         (9, 'C', '2'),
         (10, 'C', '3')

declare @firsts table
(first varchar(1))

declare @seconds table
(second varchar(1))

INSERT INTO @firsts
SELECT DISTINCT first FROM @test

INSERT INTO @seconds
SELECT DISTINCT second FROM @test

declare @firstcnt int = (SELECT count(*) FROM @firsts)
declare @secondcnt int = (SELECT count(*) FROM @firsts)

WHILE (@firstcnt > 0 AND @secondcnt > 0)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @temp
    INSERT INTO @temp 
    SELECT TOP 1 t.id, t.first, t.second FROM @test t
    INNER JOIN @firsts f On t.first = f.first
    INNER JOIN @seconds s On t.second = s.second
    ORDER BY id
    INSERT INTO @target 
    SELECT * FROM @temp
    DELETE FROM @firsts WHERE first = (SELECT first FROM @temp)
    SET @firstcnt = @firstcnt - 1
    DELETE FROM @seconds WHERE second = (SELECT second FROM @temp)
    SET @secondcnt = @secondcnt - 1
END

SELECT * FROM @target
```

This does produce the desired values and I would expect it to be faster because the while loop only needs to run for the total number of unique value pairs, rather than having to step through the entire table.

It also gives 10 C 3 as the last row, which I take to be correct, despite @Gordon's comment.  If I understand the question correctly, the ID order takes precedence: that is to say, although 'A' and 'B' have entries with '3' as the second value, these entries have a greater id, than another second value that can legitimately be inserted.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

using Recursive CTE,

```
declare @Target table(col1 varchar(20),col2 int)
declare @Test table(col1 varchar(20),col2 int)

INSERT INTO @Test (col1, col2
VALUES ('A', '2')
('A', '1')
('A', '3'),
('B', '1')
('B', '2'),
('B', '3'),
('B', '2'),
('B', '4'),
('C', '2'),
('C', '3')
    　

;With CTE as
(
select col1 ,col2
,DENSE_RANK()over( ORDER by col1)rn1
from @Test
)

,cte1 AS(
select top 1 c.col1,c.col2,rn1 from cte c where rn1=1
union ALL
select c.col1,c.col2,c.rn1 from cte c
inner join cte1 c1
on c.rn1>c1.rn
where c.col2!=c1.col2
)

insert into @Target

select col1,col2 FROM(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by col1 order by (select null)) rn2 from cte1

)t4
where rn2=1

select * from @Target
```

Comment: I am not sure but Recursive or cursor is the only way. Yes it can be optimize even though. I think if you have millions of data then you have to apply paging.